# Proving that any measure is the sum of a semi-finite measure and a measure which takes either 0 or infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need help proving that for a measure space (X, A, u) that u can be written as the sum of a semi-finite measure and a measure that takes on the values 0 and infinity.

The second measure, u_i I believe would be defined as 0 for u(s) finite, infinity for u(s) infinite.

For the first measure I would define u_f(s) = u(s) for u(s) finite but I don't know how to define u_f(s) in the case u(s) is infinite.

Thanks